# Unable to create an extended partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm, debian

Currently my host system is Debian 10.9.0, when I was first installing it I choose to use the entire disk and set up LVM (I didn't know what that meant at the time).
[installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf8sD.png)

My main issue is to set up the host system for LFS installation (Linux from Scratch). So I used minimal space for the host system (about 15GB out of 240) so I have enough space for the LFS installation.
Now the problem arises: I am not able to create an extended partition. I don't know if its because of the LVM set up earlier or not.
[<strike>My partition table</strike>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luTrX.png)
[Extended Partition option is grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sDyf.jpg) 
 I need to create an extended partition to be able to have more than 4 logical partitions.

Any tips for partition managment for LFS? I want to build LFS then delete this host system, and maybe set it up for dual boot for windows.

EDIT: i am sorry i posted the wrong image, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBMkI.png) is my actual partition table. Notice that the unlocated space is outside the extended partition already.

Comment: Debian is not on topic here. Why do you need an "extended partition"?  These are only used for MBR partitioned disks since MBR partition schemes can't have more than four true partitions. You can use GPT and you won't encounter that limitation and you will have no need for extended partitions

Comment: @Nmath To change MBR to GBT requires for me to delete the existing partition and and leads to data loss. I am sticking with extended partition because I know it works. Only this time for some reason i am not able to do that. Also yes, it doesn't have to do anything with Debian

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an extended partition: Your `/dev/sda2`, spanning the rest of that disk after `/dev/sda1`. There can only be one extended partition. But the unallocated space on your disk is inside that extended partition, so you can create more logical partitions (i.e. `/dev/sda6`, `/dev/sda7`, ...) there.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question because i realized i posted the wrong picture of my partition table. I want to have 2 extednded partition on my computer, like i said one for the current host system and one for my LFS build. In the future i want to delete my current host system so that i can switch to LFS only. This is my goal. Hope you understood me corectly. I only need to be able to create a second extended partition on my unallocated space

Comment: No: As I wrote above, there can only be ONE extended partition on a disk. This is a fixed limit; that's why gparted didn't let you create another one. You can only create (up to two) more _primary_ partitions in that unallocated space, and then partitioning tools will complain that the extended partition isn't the last one.

Comment: thanks, i got it. But one more question, is there a way to get sda5 out of the extended partition? so  i make it a primary partition and the extended partition is left for LFS build only

Comment: No easy way and no reliable way. You can try to delete both `/dev/sda5` and the extended partition `/dev/sda2` and then recreate what was `/dev/sda5` at the exact LBA address and with the exact length it had before as a primary partition (then `/dev/sda2`), possibly leaving a small gap where the header of the extended partition was. But that's a risky business, and it may go wrong, corrupting your filesystem on what was `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: If you left the defaults and the existing OS on `/dev/sda5` used UUIDs, not kernel device names (`/dev/sda5`) in `/etc/fstab` and for Grub2, you may get lucky. You might have to reinstall Grub2 (for which you might need a bootable USB stick from where you can do that). As mentioned above, it's a risky thing.

Comment: Notice that you should probably use good old `fdisk` for those operations since gparted / parted won't let you specify exact LBA addresses. Before you start, write down the exact numbers `sudo fdisk -l` so you have the exact LBA addresses and block lengths of the old `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: ok, i'll try. with me luck